# How to export browser web app from Apache Cordova framework

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap, visual-studio-cordova

I can export app as apk easily using cordova build android  but I want to export it as a webapp to use on some other browser.

cordova build browser
cordova run browser

Kindly suggest me any way to export that webapp into a file so that I can run it on any other browser for user.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Cordova to open your app in a browser. Just point a browser to the index.html in your www directory and it should open with the same behaviour as your Android app. Copy that directory and its subdirectories onto a server and it'll run in a browser just like it does on a phone or tablet.